# QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise realm id

Tags: mule, desktop, quickbooks, enterprise, quickbooks-online

Quickbooks Online has a Realm ID/Company ID. I am trying to find the same for QuickBooks desktop enterprise edition also. 
For my Enterprise edition it says null for Customer Realm ID. Can you please suggest what may be causing this? Is there any reason why it is showing as null?
Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find the same for QuickBooks desktop enterprise edition also.

There is no such thing (anymore - there used to be, but since Enterprise doens't sync with Intuit's cloud anymore, it's no longer used).

> Can you please suggest what may be causing this? Is there any reason why it is showing as null?

This is normal - Enterprise no longer syncs with Intuit's cloud anymore, so it's expected that this will be `null`.

Perhaps you can clarify why you want a `Realm ID` for Enterprise? There's no reason to have it...

Comment: thanks for your comments keith, i want a realm ID to connect to the Company QuickBooks and update records via a mulesoft integration flow.

Comment: You DO NOT NEED a realm ID for QuickBooks Enterprise. QuickBooks Enterprise DOES NOT USE realm ID values. 

Is the Mulesoft stuff for QuickBooks ONLINE instead?

Comment: we want to integrate QuickBooks Desktop Enterprise with Mulesoft to update data in QB desktop, can you please point us in direction which can help us in doing that? The basic functionality requires mulesoft flow starting and picking up data from DB and updating the same in QB desktop enterprise

Comment: Did you ask Mulesoft? They are the ones to talk to about this.